# Get information from Password Policy

Tags: c++, windows, passwords

Is there a way to get some information from Password Policy?  Like password length, max password age, etc.

I tried looking in the registry but didn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: What is it the Password Strategy? Some kind of application?

Comment: If you mean *domain Group Policy settings for password complexity, take a look at the RSoP WMI classes; E.g. `RSOP_SecuritySettingNumeric` which can be used to fetch the state of the various enforceable constraints.

Comment: Unanswerable until you tell us what "Password Strategy" is. [A Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q="password+strategy") is not helpful.

Comment: @@Cody : i want to get the value of MinimumPasswordAge,
MaximumPasswordAge, MinimumPasswordLength.. thx

Comment: i mean Password Policy not password strategy (gpedit.msc=>Windows settings=>Security Settings=>Account Policies=>Password Policy

Comment: See comment of Alex K.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NetUserModalsGet`. This is an example to get MaximumPasswordAge

```
int GetMaximumPasswordAge()
    {
        int Age = -1;
         DWORD dwLevel = 0;
       USER_MODALS_INFO_0 *pBuf = NULL;
       NET_API_STATUS nStatus;
       LPTSTR pszServerName = NULL;


       //
       nStatus = NetUserModalsGet((LPCWSTR) pszServerName,
                                  dwLevel,
                                  (LPBYTE *)&pBuf);
       //
       // If the call succeeds, print the global information.
       //
       if (nStatus == NERR_Success)
       {
          if (pBuf != NULL)
          {
              Age = pBuf->usrmod0_max_passwd_age/86400;

             printf("\tMinimum password length:  %d\n", pBuf->usrmod0_min_passwd_len);

          }
       }
       // Otherwise, print the system error.
       //
       else

          fprintf(stderr, "A system error has occurred: %d\n", nStatus);
       //
       // Free the allocated memory.
       //
       if (pBuf != NULL)
          NetApiBufferFree(pBuf);
        return Age;
    }
```